# Nginx location with optional sublocation

Tags: wordpress, nginx, angular6

I have a WordPress site with php-fpm and nginx configured. Works well.
Now I created an Angular Universal app which I want to display on the certain page. To be more specific:

I want WordPress to work here: `mysite.com/myapp`
I want Angular to work here: `mysite.com/myapp/any/path/`

I tried so many different configurations but nothing works as I want it to. For instance:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ ^/myapp/(.+)$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000/$1$is_args$args;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 60s;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    root /var/www/mysite/myapp/dist/;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/tst04.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

So as you can see I'm trying to redirect all requests starting with `/myapp/{something}` to the `http://127.0.0.1:4000` but it does not work. By "does not work" I mean that all requests are redirected to the localhost, even `/myapp/`- which I don't understand because `/myapp/` does not match the regex `/myapp/(.+)` (note the `+` sign).

I looked into the nginx error log and found that when I enter `mysite.com/myapp/` it tries to redirect it to the `upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4000/index.php"` which is not desired to me. When I enter `mysite.com/myapp/anypath/` it redirects it to the `upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4000/anypath/"` which is correct.

**Question:** why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dang! I guess I had to describe the problem somewhere to find the solution ;)
So here's what was happening:

- I make a request e.x. `mysite.com/myapp`
- Nginx matches it to the `/`location
- It runs `try_files` to the end and fires `/index.php?$args` which resolves to `/myapp/index.php`
- Nginx keeps resolving new location and it matches `^/myapp/(.+)$` so it's being redirected to the `http://127.0.0.1:4000/index.php`

Tadam! We have the explanation. Now how did I solve it? Well, the solution is pretty simple. I don't want my PHP files to be mathed against `^/myapp/(.+)$` regex so I modified it like this:

`"^/myapp/([^ php]+)$"` (note the quotation marks)

and everything started to work as expected.

Posting this in case future readers will encounter similar problem.

Comment: Why not make your app in the root, so that when you go to `mysite.com` you get the angular app, and place the backend in the subdirectory `mysite.com/admin/` or something like that?

Comment: Actually, these are requirements: `mysite.com` is a WP site, `mysite.com/myapp` is a WP page and `mysite.com/myapp/something` is an Angular app. I can't change it so I had to make it that way